# Obtaining the limiting probability of the random variable following mixed distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_{1},X_{2},....$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables . The odd ordered random variables follows the distribution:

$P(X_{2k-1}=1)=P(X_{2k-1}=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$

And all Even ordered random variables follows:

$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}e^{-\sqrt(2)|x|},$ where $-\infty < x < \infty$. It is required to obtain the probability $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P\left [ \frac{X_{1}+X_{2}+...+X_{2n}}{\sqrt(2n)}\geq1 \right ]$.

**My approach**

Since, the mean of both odd and even ordered random variables is zero, it is only required to obtain the second order moment for variance. The second order moment of odd ordered random variables turned out to be $1$ and similarly solving the Gamma integral for the even ordered moment, the second order moment is $1$ for than also. Hence, the variance of sum of $2n$ random variables is $2n$. The expression inside the Probability turned out to be standard Normal variate. So, the required probability will be $1-\Phi(1)$.

Did I do everything correctly?. My manual is not giving me any answer. Any suggestions will be very beneficial for me. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any independence properties?  If so, you can apply the central limit theorem to the odds, then to the evens, the result being a sum of two independent variables.  Alternatively, you could apply the central limit theorem to the iid random variables $Z_i= (X_i+ X_{i+1})$ for $i \in \{1, 3, 5, ..., 2n-1\}$.

Comment: Yes, I applied the central limit theorem. Have I obtained correct result?

Comment: No they are not. Do you know the meaning of "identically distributed"?

Comment: Can't we apply the CLT in this problem?

Comment: I think the random variable which belongs to same density and are independent are called iid's.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for?  Do you want somebody to agree with you that the distribution described by $P[X=-1]=P[X=1]=1/2$ is the same as the distribution described by the PDF $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{-\sqrt{2} |x|}$?

Comment: I get it. Since, half of the random variables are discrete and half continuous, these random variables are not identically distributed. Sorry

Comment: Then, we can apply CLT to both distribution seperately. Can we?

Comment: The easiest way is likely in my "Alternatively" comment, $$ \sum_{i=1}^{2n}X_i = \underbrace{(X_1+X_2)}_{Z_1} + \underbrace{(X_3+X_4)}_{Z_3} + ... + \underbrace{(X_{2n-1}+X_{2n})}_{Z_{2n-1}}$$